# SQL: How can I insert a row if table is empty, otherwise do nothing?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that always has 0 or 1 rows. I want to write a script that will insert a row if it is empty, and do nothing if there is a row. I tried this:

```
SELECT * CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table < 0)
   THEN (INSERT INTO table (a, b, c, d) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
   END CASE
FROM table;
```

But I get:

> FROM keyword not found where expected.

This seems like it should be pretty simple what am i doing wrong?

Comment: **NOTE** If you don't have other constraints set up. Two seperate sessions could both query your table, find it empty, and insert a row, each, resulting in two rows. To keep that from happening, set up a primary key on your table, and assign a check constraint to that PK so that it can only have one value: `create table t (PK number constraint t_pk primary key constraint T_CK1 check (PK = 1) . . .)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could restructure the query into a select/insert and use the `not exists` keywords to check if the table is empty, like so:

```
insert table (a, b, c, d)
select 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
from dual
where not exists (select 1 from table)
```

or, if it needs to be an `if` statement, similarly:

```
if not exists (select 1 from table)
    insert table (a, b, c, d) values ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Comment: This didn't work for me:INSERT INTO mytable (a, b, c, c) 
SELECT 'a' b, 'c', 'd' FROM mytable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable);              It never inserts a row, even when the table has 0 rows.

Comment: @user1134858: Use `dual` so you will get a row when myTable is empty. See edit I made to this answer.

Comment: This answer appears to be using SQL Server syntax, not Oracle. The first query needed `from` clause. Unlike SQL Server, Oracle does not support `select` without `from`. The `if` statement is not valid PL\SQL. Missing `then` and `end if` key words. And PL/SQL does not support `not exists` the comparison part an `if` statement. In PL\SQL, a variable to hold count would need to be created and populated, then the `if` tests that against `<> 0`.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance my answer predates the addition of the 'oracle' tag to the question, is why

Answer (score 0):

Use the MERGE statement with an INSERT but no UPDATE