# Insert new row into table if Count of rows in table is 0 in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, conditional-statements

I have a table APPDATA in which only 1 row should exist. I want to check with my SQL script if there is already a row in the table. If there isn't, I want to `INSERT` new row with values.

The issue here is that I'm not sure how conditionals and `IF/ELSE` statements work inside sqlite. I don't believe using a `CASE/WHEN/THEN` statement will help me.

I've tried a solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762144/sql-how-can-i-insert-a-row-if-table-is-empty-otherwise-do-nothing), but that was for Oracle and not Sqlite. Trying the top answer (reproduced below) gives me a syntax error.

```
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from APPDATA)
        INSERT INTO APPDATA(id,value_key)
                                    VALUES (001,1)
```

With the above code, I'm getting a syntax error at the beginning of the query statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `VALUES` use `SELECT` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO APPDATA(id, value_key) 
SELECT '001', 1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from APPDATA)
```

There is no need for conditional statements like `CASE`.
This query:

```
SELECT '001', 1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from APPDATA)
```

returns a row which will be inserted to the table `APPDATA` only if `APPDATA` is empty.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iNq8byL1qjbt18Yf9PKiYK/0).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and explanation. This is correct and worked.